# how to get the particular value from the response array received after wallet creation in bitgo Js

Tags: node.js

This is my array and want to get values from it:

```
{ wallet:
   Wallet {
     bitgo:
      BitGo {
        _baseUrl: 'https://test.bitgo.com',
        env: 'test',
        _baseApiUrl: 'https://test.bitgo.com/api/v1',
          del: [Function] },
     baseCoin:
      BaseCoin {
        network: [Object],
        coinKeychains: [Keychains] },
     _wallet:
      { id: '5b055bae749a9ba207410c65ff58c325',
        users: [Array],
        coin: 'tltc',
        label: 'My Test Wallet',
        m: 2,
        n: 3,
        pendingApprovals: [] } },
  userKeychain:
   { id: '47i3ygdhfhdhjfj84378r'
     users: [ '3w65gsdhfgshg93w2r2839'],
     pub: 'zsnadfsheg94t854tidghfhdhgdhh kladjfghgdhfhdhfghdhhfghgh',
     ethAddress: '0xzxder4tewre79618eceret3a2eabf6c8',
     encryptedPrv: '{}',
     prv: ' },
  backupKeychain:
   { id: '54idhjfhdj9a9ba207410c505912c1b1',
     users: [ '90jdfjgbja7007sdjbgjffc7a5065006' ],
     pub: '',
     ethAddress: '0x753ce0sdfvsdsgdf8baef8sdfesdfssfs2bdd8cb',
     prv: '',
     source: 'backup' },
  bitgoKeychain:
   { id: '5b055bad39230ccc07814e0589388100',
     users: [ '5ac1fd5563fa7007d5a17fc7a5065006' ],
     pub: '',
     ethAddress: '0xbfdgfdgdfdgfhfgtr6756ghfghfg719320fcc7e',
     isBitGo: true },
```

}

**// here want to get userKeychain, backupKeychain  and bitgoKeychain**Please help how to fetch the this value. Is there any function to access this values or need any parsing method in bitgo Js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using like : **wallet.wallet._wallet.id**
This will give you the wallet id.To get the userKeychain value use like  **wallet.userKeychain**